# Call an helper from a service

Tags: symfony

I would like to call an helper from my service.

```
$notificationService = $this->get('Notification');
```

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "get" of class

Comment: Where you call that method? Can you share your class?

Comment: It's ok, I have declare my service in the head with `use App\Bundle\Services\Notification;` and instantiated it `$notificationService = new Notification();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symfony isn't magic. Symfony is just PHP. That's the most important thing to remember when working with Symfony.

So if there is no `get()` method in your class, you can't call the method. In your controller, you extend from a base `Controller` of the FrameworkBundle. This class does contain such a method, so in a controller you can call this method.

Now, you still want to use the `Notification` service in your new service. Instead of getting it from the container, let the container inject it in your service when it's creating it. You do this with some service config:

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    app.your_service:
        class: AppBundle\Some\Class
        arguments: ['@Notification'] # <<-- this tells to inject the service
```

And then adapting this in your class:

```
class SomeClass
{
    private $nofication;

    public function __construct(NotificationInterface $notification)
    {
        $this->notification = $notification;
    }
}
```

There is a lot more to explain about this. See http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container